# Logs from spring boot with quartz not printing[using log4j2]

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I m using Spring boot with Quartz along with log4j2.properties. The logs related to quartz jobs are not getting printed. All other logs are getting printed. Should I add any specific config for getting this printed?

```
public class Scheduler {
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //following getting printed
        log.info("Scheduler is testing");
        SpringApplication.run(Scheduler.class, args);

    }

    @Scheduled(cron="*/2 * * * * *")
    public void execute() {
        //following not getting printed
        log.info("Scheduler  ....");
    }
}
```

The logs from cron are not printing. I am using log4j2.properties for configuring. The properties I am using:

```
#START
name=PropertiesConfig
#Folder location
property.filename = /Users/folder
#both console and file
appenders = console, file

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/gt.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file
#Project package base
logger.file.name=com.mypackage
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
#END
```

Comment: are you sure your `execute` method gets executed? Have you tried placing a breakpoint inside it and debug it with your IDE?

Comment: Yes. it is getting printed on console and not in the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `execute()` method just being invoked. If you're using `@Scheduled`, make sure that you have the `@EnableScheduling` annotation, for example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling // Make sure this is present
public class ScheduledTaskApplication {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            log.info("Scheduler is testing");
            SpringApplication.run(ScheduledTaskApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(cron="*/2 * * * * *")
    public void execute() {
        //following not getting printed
        log.info("Scheduler  ....");
    }
}
```

Additionally, make sure that you configured the `logging.config` property in `application.properties`:

```
logging.config=classpath:log4j2.properties
```

If you don't do this, it seems that the logging behaves weird, since the message in `main()` will be written to the proper logger, but afterwards it changes it to the `rootLogger`, causing all other messages within that class (not only the messages within `test()` to be written to the console).

Comment: That is also present. The log comes in console and not getting written to the file.

Comment: @TomJava can you add your logging configuration to your question?

Comment: added to the question.

Comment: @TomJava I was able to reproduce this. If you add the `logging.config` property in `application.properties`,  the issue should be solved. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @g00glen00b